# What does the notation $\sup_{x\in X}\inf_{y\in Y}d(x,y)$ mean?

Tags: notation

Say you have two disjoint closed sets $X$ and $Y$ in a metric space. I'm trying to interpret what $$\sup_{x\in X}\inf_{y\in Y}d(x,y)$$ means.

Does it mean that you pick a fixed $x\in X$, and then compute $\inf_{y\in Y}d(x,y)$ for this fixed $x$ as $y$ ranges over $Y$, to get a set of infimums, one for each $x\in X$, and then take the supremum of that resulting set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unravel this in the following way:

1. For every $x\in X$ let $y_x = \inf\{d(x,y)\mid y\in Y\}$.
2. Now we take $\sup\{y_x\mid x\in X\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you said.${}{}{}{}{}$